# create a validation rule that ensures either a single email or a multiple emails are comma separated with correct email format

Tags: validation-rule, validation, regular-expressions, admin

I created this Regex and tested it on online regex tester.
But when I am using the same regex in salesforce validation rule then I am unable to save it due to "Error: Syntax error"
The Below is the validation rule that I created.
Rule:- `NOT( REGEX( Reettik__Testing_Email__c  , '^(([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}),)*([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})$'))`

Can anyone figure out why its giving syntax error and not saving?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used ChatGpt and found out a working solution

The solution:-

`AND( NOT(REGEX( Reettik__Testing_Email__c , "^(([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}),)*([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})$")), OR( ISBLANK( Reettik__Testing_Email__c ), NOT(REGEX( Reettik__Testing_Email__c , "^(([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}),)*([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})$")) ) )`